# tk.Panedwindow isn't visible

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning TK and run into a problem using Panedwindow with python. Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Set top window geomotry

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)

        pane = tk.PanedWindow(self)
        pane.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


        test=tk.Label(pane,text='test')
        test.pack()

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
app=Application(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

Nothing appears in the root window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in `Application` will only be visible if the instance of `Application` is visible. It is not, because you haven't called `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance of `Application` (ie: `app`).

The other problem is more of a conceptual one. If you add a paned window but only have one pane, it will not have a divider since there is nothing to divide.

Here is a working version of your code, with a second pane so that you can more easily visualize it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Set top window geomotry

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)

        pane = tk.PanedWindow(self)
        pane.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        test=tk.Label(pane, text='test', background="pink")
        pane.add(test)

        test2 = tk.Label(pane, text="foo", background="blue")
        pane.add(test2)

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
app=Application(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
tk.mainloop()
```